# how to set word break in table th or td, when column and table-layout auto using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping this is fairly simple.

I want to keep table-layout:auto for the table, as this allows the "name" column to size gracefully, while the url column uses up the remaining space.

The problem is when the url column gets large, the table automatically sizes beyond the width.

Ideally I'd like to hide the overflow on the "url" column once it expands out beyond the size of the containing div.

In the Jsfiddle example you can see the first table sizing nicely, with the "name" column taking up the available space.

In the second table, it overruns its containing div, because of the text in the "url" column. I cant workout how to hide this overflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/RDG4T/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Test</title>

    <style>
        table {
            table-layout:auto;
        }
        table, th, td
        {
            text-align:left;
            white-space:nowrap;
            text-overflow:ellipsis;
        }


    </style>

    </head>

<div style="width:400px; border: 1px solid red; background-color:lightgrey;">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Status</th><th style="width:100%">Name</th><th style="width:100%">Url</th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred long long long name</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com/xxxxxx    </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
 </div>
 </div>

 <p/>

<div style="width:400px; border: 1px solid red; background-color:lightgrey;">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Status</th><th style="width:100%">Name</th><th style="width:100%">Url</th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred long long long name</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td>On</td><td>Fred</td><td>http://www.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you put URLs into the visible content? This is what creates the problem, and it is almost always unnecessary (unless the page is really trying to teach something *about URLs* rather than just refer to resources with URLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're giving your `div` a fixed width, just add on `overflow:hidden;` to it's style and the overflow from the table won't show.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ginovva320/CFbKR/

Comment: I don't suppose there is anyway of getting text ellipsis on this sort of overflow:hidden is there?

Comment: I don't think so, since the overflow rule is set on the `div` and not the element containing the text.

Answer (score 2):

I used, It's only work set `table-layout: fixed` is this key to making it work.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
table-layout: fixed;
```

check this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CQS55/2/) help to you

---

## Edit Updated

check this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RDG4T/3/)

Remove your inline style and now you css is

```
table {
    table-layout:auto;
}
table, th, td
{
    text-align:left;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the url column wrapping. I want it hidden

Answer (score 1):

Your div wrapper is displaying the overflow. Add overflow hidden to it. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mJgy9/)

```
div{
  overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an option to show the full url on hover you could try it this way:

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/RDG4T/1/)

HTML

```
<td>
    <span>http://reallylongstring.com</span>
</td>
```

CSS

```
span {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
span:hover {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Comment: I'd really prefer not to explicitly set the size for this column. This may be the best answer so far however.

Comment: Well, technically the column size isn't fixed :) Anything not constrained by a `<span>` will fit to any column width. Just use the span for urls :)